# How to create a policy using scp in aws where it restricts user to create an instance without using tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

need to create using SCP allowing users to create an instance only if they create tags in the process

Comment: This might help, but not sure if it is applicable to SCPs: [Use IAM tags to restrict EC2 instances or EBS volumes](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-tags-restrict/)

Answer (score 0):

To restrict creating a new instance without using a specific tag you can use [this statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_examples_tagging.html#example-require-tag-on-create):

```
{
  "Sid": "DenyRunInstanceWithNoProjectTag",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "Null": {
      "aws:RequestTag/Project": "true"
    }
  }
}
```